# How do I create an authenticated log in from through Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, loops, redirect, authentication

So I'm ultimately trying to make in node a login page. If a person attempts to go to a different location to begin with they should be routed to the login page.

I'm using "/" as the redirect to the "/login/". "/login/" contains the form to enter the username/password. Once they enter in the information it then routes back to "/".

Hitting a few problems. If I exclude the code I have for the redirect if the original url was "/" and a person goes to "/login/" then they can fill out the form and it redirects.

If I keep the code that redirects it automatically redirects to the login page and then reloads to the login page because of the redirect. It's some weird loop that I can't get out of. I know I could just put another end to the "/login/" but I'd like to keep it "/".

Any ideas on fixing the redirect loop? EDIT: So I know what the problem is. I'm not storing for comparison (not using session). Any clue on the best middleware to use for checking with session?

How about adding authentication or even adding the usernames/password to a data structure?

Below is the code I've come up with:

```
 const express = require("express"); //Express
 const path = require ("path");
 const session = require("express-session"); //Express Session
 const app = express();
 const mustache = require ("mustache");
 const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
 const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.engine('mustache', mustacheExpress());
app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'mustache')

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie:{}
 }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/') {
    res.redirect("/login/");
  }
  next();
});


const list = [
  {
    username: "",
    password: "",
   }
];

const data = {
  users:list
 };

 app.get('/login/', function (req, res) {
   res.render("users", data);
});


app.post("/", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let response = `Here are your credentials for the site: <br/>
  This is your username: ${username} <br/>
  This is your password: ${password} <br/>
  <img src="http://media1.giphy.com/media/c54YHGDH63jJC/giphy.gif"/>`
  res.send(response);
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(list);
  list.push({username:req.body.username});
  list.push({username:req.body.password});
  res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Creating login page');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If every time a user hits the root (/) they are redirected to /login, and successful login then redirects them back to the root, you clearly have a routing loop which I think you are aware of.

The easiest solution would be to establish a new route to direct the user to on successful login, /home for example. I see you are sending back a response so I will offer 2 possibilities. Also, you have 2 different handlers for the same POST route which is unnecessary. Here's what I would suggest:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);

  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;

  let response = `Here are your credentials for the site: <br/>
      This is your username: ${username} <br/>
      This is your password: ${password} <br/>
      <img src="http://media1.giphy.com/media/c54YHGDH63jJC/giphy.gif"/>`;

  // actions from duplicate route handler
  console.log(list);

  list.push({username:req.body.username});
  list.push({username:req.body.password});

  // this is assuming you are handling errors on the front end
  res.status(201).send(response);

});
```

I would then act on the success response from your api to then change routes using javascript on the front end.

```
window.location.assign(urlToNewRoute);
```

Alternatively, you could send the redirect with the response as a query string and then parse that on the front end rather than sending res.status(201).send(response).

```
res.redirect(`/home?message=${response}`);
```

It's really up to you how you want to design your api and front end site. These are just a couple of options. Realistically, you should be doing error handling in the POST route to check if the user exists, if they input the correct password etc. and then send back a 201, 400, 404 or some other concise status which can then be handled on the front end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You need to redirect back from `/login/` to `/` with some session information. Simplest way to do that would be to return a token which the controller can validate and if it's not valid, can redirect back to `/login/`. You can use JWT for token.